# ngrok https host-header causing redirecting to localhost

Tags: .net-6.0, portforwarding, ngrok, hostheaders

Pretty new to using `ngrok`. I'm trying to use it in order to expose my localhost site to the web, in order to test a 3rd-party plugin. Note that our site requires `https`, so I cannot use `ngrok` in normal `http` mode. If I run `ngrok http https://localhost:[MyPort] --domain [MyNgrokDomain]`, it starts up properly, and displays the appropriate `Forwarding` line, however, navigating to the site yields a `400 Invalid Hostname` error.

I'm able to correct that by changing my command to `ngrok http https://localhost:[MyPort] --domain [MyNgrokDomain] --host-header localhost:[MyPort]`. Now, the URL resolves, however, it automatically redirects it to `https://localhost:[MyPort]`. This works locally, but of course, fails everywhere else.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!